# Can you send an immediate thank you to a recurring donation?

Tags: recurring-contributions

I set up a recurring donation using authorize.net, have the IPN url configured, etc.  However, when someone completes a recurring contribution they do not get an email right now, or even 10-15 minutes later.

I'm assuming that the email is generated by the IPN event from authorize.net, but they don't attempt the transaction until around 6am.  (My first test had a bad URL for the callback).

Is there a way to acknowledge that the contribution commitment has been made with a somewhat immediate thank you email that can also spell out how future receipts will be delivered?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use Civirules to send an automated email: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/

Comment: This extension looks awesome.  Unfortunately if I make a rule for "pending contribution" and "has recurring..." it works, but then if the contact makes ANY other contribution (membership, event, direct non-recurring donation) during the life cycle of the recurring they get the email all over again because the conditions match.  Am I missing a logical AND that would limit it to only emailing for a new recurring?

Comment: yes, you would also set a condition for the donation type and perhaps also the condition for "first contribution of contact"?

Comment: but you could also use the 'add recurring contribution'  trigger I would assume?

Comment: What if it isn't the first time they've contributed?  Isn't this sort of a miss on the underlying core CiviCRM code?  If someone makes a recurring donations there should be some email recognition of that where the donor is told that future confirmations will come at the time that the transaction is attempted.

I may need to play with the conditions more because I'm having a hard time finding a way to make it work for any recurring contribution, regardless of if a prior contribution was made, and not for unrelated contributions.

Comment: ah i was triggering on a donation, not a "new recurring contribution".  That helped make it unique enough to not trigger errantly.

Comment: Cool! Glad it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can set Schedule reminder to send emails for status Pending.

Cheers

Pradeep